# What is the best way to move Microsoft Office 2011 to a new Mac?

Tags: migration, ms-office

I've purchased Microsoft Office for Mac Home & Office 2011 (single computer), and have installed and activated on my current Mac.

Given that I've already activated the software for my current Mac, what steps should I do to move the app to the new Mac, without having any problems re-activating the software? Would Apple's Migration Assistant automate the process completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no special steps. Install it using the installer just like you did on your old Mac. When prompted for the activation key, select "activate by phone" and input nothing, keep trying and it should provide a number to call.

Microsoft (unlike Adobe) does not have an automated system for licence deactivation. This has been a point of great angst among Mac users as it requires them to call Microsoft each and every time they move the Office application from one machine to another.

I believe the number in the US is: +1 (800) 936-5700. Your product support number may vary.

[Here is a rundown](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2391941) on activation and product key information.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: After an incomplete timemachine backup (I excluded the folder `/System/Library`) I had to do the following to get it working again on the same machine (I guess it should also work on your second Mac).

Beside the App that was installed to `/Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011` Restore these files from your previous installation:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper
/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.licensing.plist
```

Source: [this guide](http://cwl.cc/2012/02/easy-way-to-move-your-microsoft-office.html)

Answer (score 4):

[The previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130608/5472) is missing one path/folder. For simplicity here is the complete list:

```
/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/
/Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011/
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper
/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.licensing.plist
```

The above includes the apps, licensing and the Microsoft Office AutoUpdater

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Feel free to edit the question that's missing the information if you wish to make it better.