# How can I transfer my Microsoft Office Install to another Mac?

Tags: ms-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to move Microsoft Office 2011 to a new Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26019/what-is-the-best-way-to-move-microsoft-office-2011-to-a-new-mac)

I'm planning on reinstalling Mac OS Lion, but I don't have the MS Office install file or disk. Can I move my installed copy of Office to a USB drive and then back, or to another machine?

Comment: Are you currently using MS Office in Snow Leopard?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26019/what-is-the-best-way-to-move-microsoft-office-2011-to-a-new-mac.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to move the main folders to an external drive:

- /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011
- /Applications/Microsoft Messenger.app
- /Applications/Microsoft Communicator.app
- /Library/Application Support/Microsoft
- /Users/username/Library/Preferences/Microsoft
- /username/Documents/Microsoft-Userdata

Copy these Folders to the same path on your new system.

Answer (score 1):

moving it to a USB will most likely not work, however if you've got the license key you can go on the office website http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads and download the installer.